# circularArrayRotation algorithm ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

I am using [hacker rank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation/) and I do not understand why my ruby code only works for one test case out of like 20.  Here is the question:

> John Watson knows of an operation called a right circular rotation on
> an array of integers. One rotation operation moves the last array
> element to the first position and shifts all remaining elements right
> one. To test Sherlock's abilities, Watson provides Sherlock with an
> array of integers. Sherlock is to perform the rotation operation a
> number of times then determine the value of the element at a given
> position.
>
> For each array, perform a number of right circular rotations and
> return the values of the elements at the given indices.
>
> Function Description
>
> Complete the circularArrayRotation function in the editor below.
>
> circularArrayRotation has the following parameter(s):
>
> - `int a[n]`: the array to rotate
> - `int k`: the rotation count
> - `int queries[1]`: the indices to report
>
> Returns
>
> `int[q]`: the values in the rotated `a` as requested in `m`
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line contains 3 space-separated integers, `n`, `k`, and `q`, the number of elements in the integer array, the rotation count and the number of queries. The second line contains `n` space-separated integers,
> where each integer `i` describes array element `a[i]` (where `0 <= i < n`). Each of the `q` subsequent lines contains a single integer, `queries[i]`, an index of an element
> in `a` to return.
>
> Constraints
>
> Sample Input 0
>
> ```
> 3 2 3
> 1 2 3
> 0
> 1
> 2
> ```
>
> Sample Output 0
>
> ```
> 2
> 3
> 1
> ```

Here is my code :

```
def circularArrayRotation(a, k, queries)
    q = []
    
    while k >= 1
        m = a.pop()
        a.unshift m
        k = k - 1
    end
    
    for i in queries do
     v = a[queries[i]]
    q.push v
    
    end 
    
    return q

end
```

It only works for the sample text case but I can't figure out why.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Do you intend to push all `v`s onto `q`? Because that part of the code isn't in the `for` block.

Comment: Also, you realize that your algorithm is of quadratic time complexity. `unshift`ing an array rewrites the whole thing.

Comment: Yeah I want all of the array a "circularlized" k times and I want all of the vs from the for loop in q so I can return q which is the answer.  I dont get why it works exactly like the sample case but in the test cases maybe when bigger numbers and arrays are involved it doesnt work

Comment: I finally figured out what was going on but it was really difficult to figure it out with the limited information given.  I think it would really help if you were to clarify your question a bit.  To start with, it would be nice if you could show a completed example showing how you're entering the ```a```, ```k```, and ```queries``` arguments in an actual "test".  In addition, it would help if you would show an example of a failed test.

Comment: @user1984 that part of the code is inside the `for` loop, unlike python, ruby is not whitespace dependent the block opens with `do` and closes with `end` so `q.push v` is included in the loop. That being said I have no idea what this code is actually trying to do

Comment: A little cheating: `queries.each{|q| puts a[(q-k+a.size) % a.size]}`

Comment: What did you figure out Michael?  Here is a link to the actual question and that has the environment and sample inputs for my question on there as well as failed tests if you hit the submit button: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation/problem?utm_campaign=challenge-recommendation&utm_medium=email&utm_source=24-hour-campaign

Comment: I figured out what you were even talking about and I figured out how and what needed to be used for your method arguments.  Please note that we shouldn't need to open links to understand your problem.  It should all be right there in the question text.  Having said that, the example shown in your link is much more clear since they clearly show which elements are defined as arrays and such.  Giving us sample input lines without any clear context as to how that information is being used in your code is really difficult to understand.

Comment: Your sample input should read something more like this:  ```a = [1, 2, 3]```, ```k = 2```, and ```queries = [0, 1, 2]```

and this would make your successful attempt make more sense...```circularArrayRotation(a, k, queries) #=> [2, 3, 1]```.  We can only guess at what the failed test looks like.

Comment: thank you, @engineersmnky, good to know. I'm not a ruby person.

Comment: More Ruby-like (but still not efficient) would be to write `q.times {  a.unshift(a.pop) }; a.values_at(*queries)`. Note that this mutates `a` (as does your own code), which does not appear to violate the rules of the game.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't ran any benchmarks, but this seems like a job for the aptly named [`Array.rotate()`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-rotate) method:

```
def index_at_rotation (array, num_rotations, queries)
  array = array.rotate(-num_rotations)
  queries.map {|q| array[q]}
end

a = [1, 2, 3] 
k = 2
q = [0,1, 2]  

index_at_rotation(a, k, q)
#=>  [2, 3, 1]
```

Handles negative rotation values and `nil` results as well:

```
a = [1, 6, 9, 11]
k = -1
q = (1..4).to_a


index_at_rotation(a, k, q)
#=>  [9, 11, 1, nil]
```

Comment: You can greatly improve efficiency by rotating `q` times just once rather  `q` times for each element of `queries`: `array.rotations(-num_rotations).values_at(*queries)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, silly me.  Good catch.  I'll edit my post with a modified approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any errors in your code, but I would like to suggest a more efficient way of making the calculation.

First observe that after `q` rotations the element at index `i` will at index `(i+q) % n`.

For example, suppose

```
n = 3
a = [1,2,3]
q = 5
```

Then after `q` rotations the array will be as follows.

```
arr = Array.new(3)
arr[(0+5) % 3] = a[0] #=> arr[2] = 1
arr[(1+5) % 3] = a[1] #=> arr[0] = 2
arr[(2+5) % 3] = a[2] #=> arr[1] = 3
arr                   #=> [2,3,1]
```

We therefore can write

```
def doit(n,a,q,queries)      
  n.times.with_object(Array.new(n)) do |i,arr|
    arr[(i+q) % n] = a[i]
  end.values_at(*queries)
end
```

```
doit(3,[1,2,3],5,[0,1,2])
  #=> [2,3,1]
doit(3,[1,2,3],5,[2,1])
  #=> [1, 3]
doit(3,[1,2,3],2,[0,1,2])
  #=> [2, 3, 1]
p doit(3,[1,2,3],0,[0,1,2])
  #=> [1,2,3]
doit(20,(0..19).to_a,25,(0..19).to_a.reverse)
  #=> [14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5,
  #    4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15]
```

---

Alternatively, we may observe that after `q` rotations the element at index `j` was initially at index `(j-q) % n`.

For the earlier example, after `q` rotations the array will be

```
[a[(0-5) % 3], a[(1-5) % 3], a[(2-5) % 3]]
  #=> [a[1], a[2], a[0]]
  #=> [2,3,1]
```

We therefore could instead write

```
def doit(n,a,q,queries)
  n.times.map { |j| a[(j-q) % n] }.values_at(*queries)
end
```

Comment: Thank you.  That is all very interesting and I learned a bunch!